# Using s3 Bucket for personal site, GET Requests increasing no idea how

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3, bucket

So I have a Django 1.8 application on heroku.

Only the app is in Heroku, static and media files are hosted on a S3 Bucket from Amazon Web Services.

I am using the free tier, the weird thing is that according to this month report (which is just pass 10 days) I am 93.65% of my free requests (18,729.00/20,000 Requests).

My web app is not even popular or starred on any social network, in fact, according to Google Analytics I have around 50 sessions and 1000 pageviews. My guess is that some Hotlinking is happening or I am not understanding how GET requests are being measured.

If the hotlinking theory is right, I'm trying to set a policy for "HTTP referer" with no luck so far.

Any ideas?

Comment: Enable bucket logging, then check the logs to see where the requests are coming from. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/ManagingBucketLogging.html

Comment: I did that. No luck. I need to add another filter like Referer or HASH but I don't know how.